# JEST-angular 14.2 - SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest

Getting the below error while running npx jest. Tried various solutions using ts-jest & babel, yet no breakthrough.

**Details:
**    C:\Dev\carepole\carepole-frontend\node_modules\slash\index.js:1
({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export default function slash(path) {
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)

**jest.config.ts**

```
 const jestConfig: Config.InitialOptions = {
  moduleDirectories: ["<rootDir>/node_modules/"],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts)?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$': 'babel-jest'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
     "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!slash)"
  ],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  preset: "jest-preset-angular",
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts"],
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "json", "jsx", "ts", "tsx", "json"],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
    },
  },

};
```

export default jestConfig;

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-typescript", "@babel/preset-env"],

  env: {
    test: {
      plugins: ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"],
    },
  },
};
```

**setUpJest.ts**

```
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
```

JEST test cases with angular 14 fail with error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'